# Win2012 Won't run scheduled task to sleep any more - but does after login

Tags: windows-server-2012

This has got me stumped. A very reliable long time Win2012 server - suddenly stops running scheduled tasks. The server is run headless - and I remote into with Remote Desktop. Admin account is logged in all the time.

I run a scheduled task to make the server sleep at night. Scheduled Tasks just won't initiate it any longer. I've tried all the options. None work. I've tried different dedicated sleep apps (such as Wise Auto Shutdown and Z-Cron) with the same results.

All attempts will work when:

- on demand
- or when I log back into the server with Remote Desktop right after the task was meant to be run. It seems that triggers the event.

What is strange is that other scheduled events continue to work as normal - such as the scheduled wake up task.

I've checked permissions, and as much as I can - with no fix.

I've not been able to find anyone else with the same issue. Any hints would be appreciated. But again, this is not isolated to Windows Scheduler - as the same thing happens with other apps. The server just doesn't want to sleep (or hibernate) on it's own any longer (after doing so for many years).

Thanks (first post here).

Comment: Any logs? Whats the state shown in the scheduler?

Comment: Thanks for asking - I was delaying an answer, as it seems the server has fixed itself. The only change was applying the latest updates from MS - perhaps something in there was fixed. It's strange indeed. But happy it's now back to behaving itself like it has for years.

Comment: I spoke too soon. It's back again. Nothing in the logs to show why it's happening (that I can see). I think I'll just trash this OS and install latest OS instead.

Comment: It's been a few days, and all is back to normal - I don't know why. System is put to sleep automatically by Task Scheduler at set time.